# Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE' Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem when try to create a client, who has a few addresses.

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Lastname{ get; set; }
    public int DNI { get; set; }
    public List<Phones> Phones{ get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    [Key]
    public int IdPhone { get; set; }
    public int Number{ get; set; }
}

public Client Create(Client client)
{
    if (_context.Client.Any(x => x.DNI == cliente.DNI))
        throw new AppException("Username " + cliente.DNI + " is already taken");

    _context.Cliente.Add(client);
    _context.Phones.AddRange(client.Phones);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return client;
}
```

Exception is:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> SqlException : Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'

```
{
"name": "Franco",
"lastname": "Pachue",
"dni": 55555555,
"phones": [
    {
        "number": "4444444"
    }
]

}
```

Comment: If `Phones` is part of `Client`, why are you adding `Phones` manually? EF does that for you already. You can remove the call to `_context.Phones.AddRange(client.Phones);`

Comment: The problem is the same without that. Added the request.

Comment: You will need to either turn on Entity Framework logging or use SQL Server Profiler (if running SQL Server) to see the generated SQL. I'd guess there's something wrong in how your entities are defined in the context

Comment: A request without phones works fine.

Comment: That's an SQL error - we need to see the SQL code (even though you may not be directly writing it yourself) to have a chance of working out what is generating the error. To diagnose that back to something you have written yourself, we'd need to see the mapping also.

Comment: That's a very low-level error. Frankly something you should never see when using Entity Framework. In other words, you seem to have stumbled upon a bug. As a result, you should file it with the EF Core issue tracker. However, before you do. Ensure you're running the latest stable EF Core release (just in case it's already been fixed). Then, you need to provide a complete and reproduceable example. Provide as much info as you can. The exact exception, stack trace, versions of various libraries and SQL Server, etc.

Comment: Are you perhaps running SQL Server 2005 for your database? EF Core only supports 2008+, and the `MERGE` keyword is only supported in 2008+ too.

Comment: Oh, have SQL Server 2005 in this PC,I did not realize, i had to install mssql 2017 and works fine, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the AddRange.
Just add a ClientId to the Phone entity (assuming that one phone will only belong to one client). The phones will be then saved when adding a Client.

```
public class Client
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name{ get; set; }
public string Lastname{ get; set; }
public int DNI { get; set; }
public List<Phones> Phones{ get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
[Key]
public int IdPhone { get; set; }
public int Number{ get; set; }
public int ClientId { get; set; }
public Client Client { get; set; }
}

public Client Create(Client client)
{
if (_context.Client.Any(x => x.DNI == cliente.DNI))
    throw new AppException("Username " + cliente.DNI + " is already taken");

_context.Client.Add(client);
_context.SaveChanges();

return client;
}
```